# What field structure would be better for a definition table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, md5

I'm making a dictionary webapp. The user will search for words. Would it be faster to do this?

```
SELECT * from definition WHERE word LIKE "house";
```

or...

```
SELECT * from definition WHERE word_hash LIKE md5("house");
```

In the second example, I store the md5() value of words in the word_hash field. Of course, "word" and "word_hash" are indexes.

**Update**: sometimes, the word field could be more than 1 word. Example: Sacré Bleu

Comment: I would assume the word search would be faster in most cases (where it's length is shorter than that of the hash)

Comment: what if, for some reason, there would be more than 1 word in the definition? example: Sacré Bleu (french)

Comment: If my theory of word search (and I'm assuming any speedup would not be significant) is correct, the word is still faster.  The hash for that/those words is '80d42badd4395b5733ee6e594773776e', a bit longer than the words combined.  Also, you are adding the cost of a hash, whereas version #1 doesn't have that.

Comment: Can you not just write a test for a million dictionary entries and just test it?

Comment: @KileyNaro, that's even better than guessing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping LIKE completely would be faster. Added the lower case version of `word` as `word_lc`, index `word_lc`, and then do:

```
select * from definition where word_lc = lower(word_you_want)
```

Using LIKE without any `%` or `_` wildcards is just a case insensitive equality test so you should go straight to a case insensitive comparison that can and will take advantage of an index. Also, as usual, say what you mean so the computer can do what you want it to do.

Comment: Great tip. What about if the user types "houze" instead, is there a way for MySQL to find similar matches to recommend the user a correction?

Comment: @andufo: LIKE won't help you very much with that and `LIKE md5(...)` will help even less. Maybe have a look at MySQL's full-text search or do some "mysql fuzzy search" googling.